# For each member of a list, write it to a separate file, python

Tags: python, list, file-io

I have a list of length n.  Each item of the list need to be written to n .txt files.  For some reason the following, basic approach isn't working for me:

```
for item in lst:
     for i in range(len(lst)):
         write_to_me = open('list_item_%i.txt' %i, 'w') 
         write_to_me.write(item)
```

The file names are fine ('list_item_0.txt', 'list_item_1.txt', etc.) but the SAME item is being written to each file.  So I end up with n files with duplicate contents in each file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use nested loops. Use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get both the index and the item:

```
 for i, item in enumerate(lst):
     write_to_me = open('list_item_{0}.txt'.format(i), 'w') 
     write_to_me.write(item)
     write_to_me.close()
```

Sidenote: Don't forget to close the files when you have finished using them!